# InertiaJS not connecting to React component - Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs

I'm following along with [This Tutorial from Laravel Bootcamp](https://bootcamp.laravel.com/inertia/creating-chirps#inertia).

I can't seem to get my controller to read my JS files from my resources folder. I'm not even getting an error!

Here's where my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Chirp;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Inertia\Response;

class ChirpController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('Chirps/Index', [
            //
        ]);
    }

    // ...
    // empty methods down here
    // ...
}
```

And here's where the JS component is located:
[file location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qjIH.png)

I've made sure that my file names are correct. I've tried all caps combinations. I've started this project over again a bunch of times to make sure I followed Laravel Bootcamp's instruction's as closely as possible.

I am not getting any errors, even when I intentionally mess up my JS component. Also, when I put `return Response("Testing...");` in my controller, it comes through just fine, so...

I believe the problem has to do with linking Inertia to my JS component.

Any ideas?

Comment: run `npm run watch`

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser console for errors. It probably says that *user* is not defined with a reference to AuthenticatedLayout, a React component that is used in your Index.jsx.

AuthenticatedLayout takes a property called *user*, which is not given in Index.jsx. If you compare it to for example /Pages/Dashboard.jsx, you will see a property is defined "user={auth.user}" for the AuthenticatedLayout component.

Try adding that to the AuthenticatedLayout component in your Pages/Chirps/Index.jsx.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in the same spot. Here's what I changed on the top of the Chirps/Index.jsx

```
export default function Index(props) {
  const { data, setData, post, processing, reset, errors } = useForm({
    message: "",
  })

  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    post(route("chirps.store"), { onSuccess: () => reset() })
  }

  return
    <AuthenticatedLayout auth={props.auth} user={props.auth.user} />
}
```